# How to config: proxy for all ipv4 and no proxy for all ipv6

Tags: firefox, proxy, ipv6

How can I set the manual proxy configuration on firefox, so that let proxy for all ipv4, but no proxy for all ipv6?

Answer (score 1):

There is limited support for IPv6 addresses in browser proxy configuration rules, some support IPv6 address network/masks in this format `[ff08::0/64]`.

There's additional limited support in proxy auto configuration files.
One answer with more references here: [Serverfault "Using IPv6 Addresses in Proxy PAC"](https://serverfault.com/questions/267280/using-ipv6-addresses-in-proxy-pac)

This question may be more appropriate for SuperUser - but since this is programming - the javascript-based Proxy PAC is the way to go.  `IsInNet()` or `shExpMatch()` can select IPv6 addresses.

```
function FindProxyForURLEx(url, host) {
  if (shExpMatch(dnsResolveEx(host), "*:*"))
  {
    return "DIRECT";
  } else {
    return "PROXY myproxy:8123";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

That doesn't make sense. Web browsers decide whether or not they are going to use a proxy server before finding out which address family is going to be used. If a proxy server is to be used, it's the proxy server that will resolve the hostname and choose which address family to use. The user agent will never even know which one was used. If no proxy server is used, then the user agent will be responsible for making the connection instead, using whatever address family is available.

Comment: This isn't technically true. Sometimes the address is provided in the URL, or a DNS lookup occurs before connecting, and the resultant address affects the selection of a proxy.